# Vec1 = Circle centre, Vec2 = mousepos, find the point on the circle between Vec1, Vec2

Tags: vector, rotation, geometry, 2d

I have two vectors: one is in the centre of a circle, another is at the mouse position. I want to find the point on the circle that is between the two vectors.

I specifically want the answer in terms of circle centre + diameter, not trigonometry. So, Circle centre + circle diameter (in the direction of) the mouse position.

If it helps, think of a clock. I need the vector coordinance of the 'number' the 'hand' is pointing to. The hand is always pointing toward the variable vector 'mouse position'.

I want 'the point'(vec2d_X) *on the circle* between the 'centre of the clock' (vec2d_1) and the 'mouse position'(vec2d_2).

See also this follow up question:
[Determine rotation direction /toward/ variable point on a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925163/determine-rotation-direction-toward-variable-point-on-a-circle)

EDIT>>>>>>

Is using trig faster?

```
#Python
def circlepoint_trig(vertex, mousepos, circlepoint):
    angle = math.atan2(mousepos[1] - vertex[1], mousepos[0] - vertex[0])
    myx = 80 * math.cos(angle) #80 is length of clock 'hand'
    myy = 80 * math.sin(angle) #80 is length of clock 'hand'
    circlepoint = vec2d(myx,myy) + vertex
    return circlepoint
```

Comment: does your vector1 contain 2 points?

Comment: Yes. The two points are the center of the 'clock' and the mouse position.

Comment: The point I am looking for is essential the 'clock' centre + the length of the hand, along the vector of the centre of the clock and mouse position.

Comment: sorry i didn't completely understand your question.but if you have two coordinates p1(x1,y1) and p2(x2,y2) the midpoint of this 2 given by ( (x1+x2)/2 , (y1+y2)/2).

Comment: Yes, I found the midpoint. I need the point that is on the edge of the 'circle' between the centre of the circle and the mouse position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`radius_vector = mouse_position - circle_center`

`normalized_vector = radius_vector * circle_radius / radius_vector.length()`

`circle_point = circle_center + normalized_vector`

Clarification:

`vector.length=sqrt(vector.x*vector.x+vector.y*vector.y)`

Comment: My vec2d doesn't have .length; could you explain how that works?

Comment: Do you think your formula will perform faster than the trig formula? (see question edit)

Comment: @CodeHard_or_HardCode, It's better to measure. On old CPUs I would say my formula would be faster (since atan2, sin, cos are slower), but new CPUs implement more and more things in hardware, so I don't know.

Comment: I tested it and it seems your formula is 5-10x faster in nano time. That's according to java's nano function and assuming I implemented it right.